# Redirecting to subfolder, but also redirect http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https, subdirectory

I am doing a redirection from an URL directly to an subfolder (example: redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/subfolder`), which is working perfectly as following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Additionally (if possible using the same .htaccess file) I would like to redirect any http to https, which works fine using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [L]
```

How do I combine those two redirections into one .htaccess file? So finally the redirection from http to https *and* the redirection to the subfolder?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
#http to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
#Rewrite everything to subfolder
RewriteRule !subfolder /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works, but with the following modification:

Replace the 3rd line of code with:
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

Once again thank you!